# Does CXF 3.1.X uses Apache HttpComponents - HttpClient?

Tags: cxf, apache-httpclient-4.x, ntlm, ntlmv2

Does CXF 3.1.x really uses [Apache HttpComponents - HttpClient](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/) for http transport? Maven dependencies does not list "Apache HttpComponents" as dependency nor do I see any [HttpClient](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpclient/apidocs/org/apache/http/client/HttpClient.html) class in the CXF jars? However [CXF JIRA CXF-6704](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CXF-6704) discusses about it?

I need access to HttpClient in CXF for [NTLM support per connection basis](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/ntlm.html) which [CXF by default relies](http://cxf.apache.org/docs/client-http-transport-including-ssl-support.html#ClientHTTPTransport(includingSSLsupport)-NTLMAuthentication) on [Java 6+ Authenticator](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/net/http-auth.html) which is set per JVM.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CXF has a decoupled runtime layer. Mostly they start with cxf-rt-*.

In the case of transports, cxf-rt-transports-*.

Take a look at [this](http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Corg.apache.cxf%7Ccxf-rt-transports-http-hc%7C3.1.11%7Cbundle). I believe that this is the HTTP Components transport runtime.

EDIT: I think this is for asynchronous transport - (looked at the pom after I posted this).

EDIT2: I did a little more research on this and found [this documentation](http://cxf.apache.org/docs/asynchronous-client-http-transport.html). It says that the async client can be used for synchronous calls by setting use.async.http.conduit bus property to true. This also specifically refers to NTLM authentication.

Comment: ah! I see * -hc (httpclient). Any idea how to access "HttpClient" instance CXF would use behind the scenes?

Comment: Does CXF uses HttpClient for async web services only?

Comment: I'm checking that now - I'm not 100% sure of the transport mech at the moment.

Comment: I've unfortunately led you into a very complex area of the CXF runtime. The HTTP Client functionality is provided as a Conduit. This is kind of an interceptor around a particular soap port. That said, you may have to slog through some source code: https://github.com/apache/cxf/blob/3.1.x-fixes/rt/transports/http-hc/src/main/java/org/apache/cxf/transport/http/asyncclient/AsyncHTTPConduit.java. As for getting the actual HttpClient, that is stored as an attribute on the Conduit implementation which you /may/ be able to reach from an interceptor.

Comment: I have already read CXF async and NTLM docs, unfortunately my requirements are not for async services

Comment: As I tried to state, this can be used for synchronous requests even though the underlying handler is asynchronous